# UIbutton in UItableviewcell of UItableview help?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have searched stackoverflow to find an answer but i can not find one.

I have an uibutton in an uitableviewcell of an uitableview.

I tap on it. When i tap on it a function is triggered. Inside the function i am trying to get the indexpath of the uitableviewcell. The indexpath should be the one where the button i pressed previously exists. The function is triggered but i get a nil value when i access indexpath.

this is the code i use

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [walltablefriends indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview]];
```

but it is not working it is giving me 'nil' . Any help appreciated!

Comment: How did you add the button to the cell? If in code, did you add it to the cell or the cell's content view?

Comment: also, just a sanity check: you've verified while stepping through that walltablefriends is not nil, right?

Comment: This is how i add the button  [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];

Comment: dreylin i think you are right the walltablefriends table is nil!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table was empty as dreylin mentioned in a comment! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that the buttons superview is a UITableViewCell is a dangerous thing, for instance if you add the button to the content view property of the cell then it's superview is a UIView not the cell view.

I would subclass my tableview cell and make that the target for the button press, and have a delegate for the cell which tells your view controller that the cell action was selected, something like this...

```
- (void)tableCellActionSelected:(MyCellClass *)aCell;
```

The cell can then call...

```
[cellDelegate tableCellActionSelected:self];
```